# Update TreeView on custom TreeItem property change

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, groovyfx

I have extended TreeCell and TreeItem class.  MyTreeItem contains a custom property which I use inside MyTreeCell to render graphics/font etc.  The problem is when I set MyTreeCell.customProperty I'm not sure how to make the TreeView/Cell redraw.

For example:

```
public class MyTreeItem extends TreeItem {
    Object customProperty

    public void setCustomProperty(Object customProperty) {
        this.customProperty = customProperty

        // how to fire a change event on the TreeView?
    }
}
```

Any comments on the solution or (lack of) design approach appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just use a default `TreeItem` implementation and use its `value` property for this use case? The tree cell will by default observe that property, so you wouldn't need any additional wiring like this.

Comment: I have special items which have a display value but are not associated with my model. I may be able to create a class instead which wraps the display value and associated object.

Comment: Try to clear and re-set the valueProperty, it may trigger the updateItem which then updates your cell rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two approaches (not including the hack of nulling the value, as suggested in the comments)

One is to manually fire a TreeModificationEvent when setting the custom property, that is in your setCustomProperty:

```
public class MyTreeItem extends TreeItem {
    Object customProperty

    public void setCustomProperty(Object customProperty) {
        this.customProperty = customProperty
        TreeModificationEvent<T> ev = new TreeModificationEvent<>(valueChangedEvent(), this);
        Event.fireEvent(this, ev);
    }
}
```

Another is to make the custom property a "real" property and let interested parties (f.i. your custom TreeCell) listen to changes of that property. For an example of how to implement (and re-wire) the listener have a look at how DefaultTreeCell handles the graphicProperty of a TreeItem.

Which to choose depends on your context: the first makes sure that all listeners to TreeModificationEvents are notified, the second allows to implement a general TreeCell taking a property (factory) of the treeItem to visualize.

Comment: Firing the event solved the issue, though I agree with James_D to stick with value.